# JDBC Derby DriverManager.getConnection() results in SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: jsp, jdbc, derby

I am using a Derby database and trying to connect to it in my JSP application. I am trying to get a connection of the database by calling DriverManager.getConnection() with correct URL and database credentials. However, this results in:

**java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Network protocol exception: DSS chained with same id at end of same id chain parse.  The connection has been terminated.**

Why is that?

Comment: Is there anything deeper in the exception? Paste the whole thing into your question: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this error is invalid user name or password in the connection string. Put the correct user name and password in property file.

```
    <property name="username" value="dbUsername" />
    <property name="password" value="yourpwd"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

Here is my stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Netzprotokollausnahme: Das nächste DDS-Segment der Kette hat dieselbe ID wie das aktuelle Segment. Die Verbindung wurde beendet.
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        [...]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: Netzprotokollausnahme: Das nächste DDS-Segment der Kette hat dieselbe ID wie das aktuelle Segment. Die Verbindung wurde beendet.
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.Reply.endOfSameIdChainData(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.readAccessDatabase(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.readSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowUSRIDPWDconnect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowConnect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

I post this additional stack-trace because of the german error-messages. Hopefully the next one with the same error and german text can find this question and the solution.
(I would have added it as a comment to the question but can't because of missing reputation.)

The solution was, as @vels4j mentioned a wrong user/password (my user had a blank/tab in the end).